# What does 'the spirits of the prophets are subject to the prophets' mean in 1 Cor 14:32?

Tags: 1-corinthians, prophecy, spirit

1 Cor 14:32 (Revised Version)

> and the spirits *(πνεύματα)* of the prophets *(προφητῶν)* are subject to the prophets;

What is the meaning of:

1. *spirits of the prophets*
2. *subject to the prophets*

in this verse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Corinthians 14:

> 29 Two or three prophets should speak, and the others should weigh carefully what is said. 30And if a revelation comes to someone who is sitting down, the first speaker should stop. 31For you can all prophesy **in turn** so that everyone may be instructed and encouraged. 32The spirits of prophets are subject to the control of prophets. 33For God is not a God of **disorder** but of peace—as in all the congregations of the Lord’s people.

Paul did not want disorderly behaviors during the worship service, particularly from the so-called prophets. The prophets should be able to control their spirits to behave orderly.

Comment: So, a member of the Corinthian church (not the apostles) who had the gift of prophecy was called by the name of prophet. That's interesting.